# How to sort an array in PHP in a specific way

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, foreach

Code:

```
$array = array('even' => array(array('key' => 'test','key2' => 'Wn'), array('key' => 'test3', 'key2' => 'Bx')),
                'not_even' => array(array('key' => 'test2','key2' => 'Xn'), array('key' => 'test4', 'key2' => 'Gy')),
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test
                    [key2] => Wn
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test3
                    [key2] => Bx
                )

        )

    [not_even] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test2
                    [key2] => Xn
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test4
                    [key2] => Gy
                )

        )

)
```

I want sort it and result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => test
            [key2] => Wn
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => test2
            [key2] => Xn
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => test3
            [key2] => Bx
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => test4
            [key2] => Gy
        )

)
```

So how sort it? Keys in arrays should be:
test
test2
test3
test4.
How use foreach or something else for this? What is the best solution.
Important is "key", "key2" is not matter.

Comment: You don't want to sort the array, you want to re-organize its data (and maybe sort it, it's not clear from the question). `foreach()` is a simple solution. The PHP functions [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) could also help. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example and i have tested in my system and it's working perfectly.

```
<?php
$array = array('even' => array(array('key' => 'test','key2' => 'Wn'), array('key' => 'test3', 'key2' => 'Bx')),
                 'not_even' => array(array('key' => 'test2','key2' => 'Xn'), array('key' => 'test4', 'key2' => 'Gy')),
);
//Before Sorting
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

$my_array = array();
foreach($array as $values){
$my_array = array_merge($my_array, $values);
}

//After Sorting
asort($my_array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_array );
echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

**OutPut:-**

```
Array
(
    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test
                    [key2] => Wn
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test3
                    [key2] => Bx
                )

        )

    [not_even] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test2
                    [key2] => Xn
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => test4
                    [key2] => Gy
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => test
            [key2] => Wn
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => test2
            [key2] => Xn
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => test3
            [key2] => Bx
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => test4
            [key2] => Gy
        )

)
```

I think this is want you need.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array = array('even' => array(array('key' => 'test5','key2' => 'Wn'),    array('key' => 'test10', 'key2' => 'Bx')),
'not_even' => array(array('key' => 'test1','key2' => 'Xn'), array('key' => 'test', 'key2' => 'Gy')),
);

$new_array = array();

// changing  structure
foreach($array as $values){
$new_array = array_merge($new_array, $values);
}

// dump array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array );
echo '</pre>';

// sorting
/// function for sorting
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   return strcasecmp($a['key'], $b['key']);
}

// sort by 'key' 
uksort($new_array, "cmp");

// dump array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array );
echo '</pre>';
```

Note: this is string sorting so test10 < test5

Comment: it is not clear what by what you want to sort. From you code I see that structure of an array has been changed. But not sorted.

Comment: Your ansewer is good but it is not exactly what I want. The Result should be: $new_array[0][key] => test, $new_array[1][key] => test2 and so on, not $new_array[0][key] => test, $new_array[1][key] => test3.. so modulo or something like this on keys?

Comment: updated the code, now it is being sorted. You can also change the logic of "cmp" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php)

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
   $array1[$key]  = $row[0]; 
}

array_multisort($array1, SORT_DESC, $array);
```